# How to fix an error: /AccountDemo.java:53: error: missing return statement } ^ 1 error

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an error as follows:

```
/AccountDemo.java:53: error: missing return statement   }   ^ 1 error
```

I have tried everything. How can I fix this problem?

```java
class Account
{
    private int number;


    public int getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number1)
    {
        number=number1;
    }

}

public class AccountDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Account[] objArray= new Account[5];

        objArray[0].setNumber(7);
        objArray[1].setNumber(3);
        objArray[2].setNumber(5);
        objArray[3].setNumber(4);
        objArray[4].setNumber(9);

        int accountres= searchAccountByNumber(objArray, 63);
        System.out.println("Output after first search: "+accountres);

        int accountres1= searchAccountByNumber(objArray, 4);
        System.out.println("Output after second search: "+accountres1);
    }

    public static int searchAccountByNumber(Account[] objArray,int s)
    {
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(objArray[i].getNumber()==s)
            {
                return i;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't tag Java code with C and C++!!

Comment: What happens if the `for` loop never was entered?  The compiler does not know that it will always be entered.  You need a `return` in all possible branches.

Comment: The whole `for` loop looks a bit pointless, to me. Once entered, it will *never* reach the next iteration.

Comment: The `else` should probably be deleted and the `return -1;` should be outside the loop at the end of the function.  Otherwise, you return `-1` unless the first element in the array matches, which seems a bit pointless — you don't need a loop for that!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by assigning a variable to it rather than directly returning it, looks as if it works.

```
 class Account {

    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number1) {
        number = number1; }

}public class AccountDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Account[] objArray = new Account[5];

        objArray[0].setNumber(7);
        objArray[1].setNumber(3);
        objArray[2].setNumber(5);
        objArray[3].setNumber(4);
        objArray[4].setNumber(9);

        int accountres = searchAccountByNumber(objArray, 63);
        System.out.println("Output after first search: " + accountres);

        int accountres1 = searchAccountByNumber(objArray, 4);
        System.out.println("Output after second search: " + accountres1);
    }

    public static int searchAccountByNumber(Account[] objArray, int s) {
        int finalreturn = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (objArray[i].getNumber() == s) {
                finalreturn = i;
            } else {
                finalreturn = -1;
            }
        }
        return finalreturn;
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: the logic is still wrong. this will return -1 if `s` is found anywhere but at the last element.

Comment: When I am  executing the above code am still getting the following error                                                    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at AccountDemo.main(AccountDemo.java:18)

Comment: @surya1616 thats because `new Account[5];` creates an array with five elements, all of which are initialized to `null`. You need to create Account objects with `new Account()`. Either manually or in a loop.